# Mvc get subcategories from category id

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller

I have 2 sql table Categories and Subcategories. In Subcategories table there is CategoryID row. How can i get subcategories for categoryid?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var model = new BlogDB();
  model.Categories = db.Categories.ToList();
  model.Subcategories = db.Subcategories.ToList();
  return View(model);
}
```

I want like this:

```
select c.Name, s.Name from Categories c left join Subcategories s on c.ID=s.CategoryID
```

And Index View is:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
    {
        <li>
            @item.Name
            <ul>
                @foreach (var sub in Model.Subcategories)
                {
                    <li>@sub.Name</li>
                }
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you have set foreign keys between two tables?

Comment: yes, i have CategoryID inside Subcategories table and set between ID inside Category table.

Comment: Then try with the answer Krishna has provided... It should work fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your datamodel is setup correctly, and assuming your Category Class has the ICollection of subcategories

```
public call Category
{
   //.
   //.
   //.
   public virtual List<Subcategory> Subcategories{get;set;}    
}

<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
    {
        <li>
            @item.Name
            <ul>
                @foreach (var sub in item.Subcategories)
                {
                    <li>@sub.Name</li>
                }
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```